# How can I hide Keyboard input in Android from Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keyboard-input

How can I hide Keyboard input in Android from Unity? can anyone please help?

> Issue in Detail:

I can not hide keyboard input in android as hide mobile input works in iOS.

> What I have tried till now:

if I use `on edit`, there is a problem that the action occurs when user tap on anyside of the screen. Need a fix.

Comment: did you try `inputField.shouldHideMobileInput = true;`

Comment: it works only for iOS.